# Codeigniter Pagination Links Errors

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, hyperlink

I am using codeigniter 2.03 and its pagination class. It has a problem that looks something like this:

1
2
next last

here is my code in controller:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url().'/admin/seesubcategory/'; //set the base url for pagination
$config['total_rows'] = $a; //total rows
$config['per_page'] = '12'; //the number of per page for pagination
$config['uri_segment'] = 3; //see from base_url. 3 for this case
$this->pagination->initialize($config); //initialize pagination
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';  
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<div>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</div>';
```

here is my code for print the links:

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

and here is my css:

```css
#pagination a, #pagination strong {
    background: #e3e3e3;
    padding: 4px 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #cac9c9;
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#pagination strong, #pagination a:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #cac9c9;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can you post html code of pagination?

Comment: You should move the $this->pagination->initialize($config); to the bottom of the $config array.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like this

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url().'/admin/seesubcategory/'; //set the base url for pagination
$config['total_rows'] = $a; //total rows
$config['per_page'] = '12'; //the number of per page for pagination
$config['uri_segment'] = 3; //see from base_url. 3 for this case    
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';  
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<div>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config); //initialize pagination
```

you need to initialize the "config" at the end of all